# Server Error in Application

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, web-hosting

Whenever I am viewing my file (file is located in shared drive) to a browser, I am getting this error:

> Server Error in '/Test' Application.

**Security Exception**

> Description: The application attempted
>   to perform an operation not allowed by
>   the security policy.  To grant this
>   application the required permission
>   please contact your system
>   administrator or change the
>   application's trust level in the
>   configuration file.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission,
>   System, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.

I contacted the System Admin, he said he has given the full access rights to my PC. What is going wrong here?

Comment: You're viewing SQL files through a browser? So, you get to _view_ the file and the error occurs as the consequence of an action? I think you mean when _trying_ to view the file you get this error? What type of file is it you're attempting to access? Other than the exception message, there's a lack of real information here.

Comment: I suggest you debug your code to find which line of code throw this exception. With that, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Okay! I am having couple of buttons here and there in that webpage and that button perform some functions which is related to viewing SQL Files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default you can't host ASP.NET pages from a shared drive since this is an untrusted location.  You will need to edit your .NET configuration to allow this location.  You can find a quick guide here (The first answer): http://forums.asp.net/t/1371394.aspx

A quick test before doing that is to **copy the project locally** and run it.  If everything works, then that is your problem.  If it is important to keep the project on the shared drive you will have to follow the above steps to make it a trusted location.

Comment: +1 for suggesting files being on a shared disc not having permission

Comment: Thanks a ton! that completely fixed it for me as well.